# Ignite near cache only deployment

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to run Ignite in embedded mode, inside a Java application? So no separate Ignite installation or cluster.
The near cache feature might serve for this purpose, but I haven't found documentation about having a near cache only deployment.

Answer (score 0):

A near cache is a cache of a cache, so it does not make sense to only use a near cache!

But yes, you can embed Ignite. Any Java program with `Ignition.start()` effectively becomes a node in an Ignite server cluster. In general, it's better to have a separate cluster and have your program just be a client but lots of people do use it embedded.